# How to cluster multivariate time series on different datasets?

Tags: time-series, classification, clustering, multivariate-analysis, k-means

I have following issue: I am trying to cluster similar countries with respect to different temporal features. Therefore, I have twelve different datasets each representing a different country. Each dataset contains of a couple of features as time series. The features can differ from dataset to dataset (e. g., dataset1 = feature A, feature C, feature E, ...; dataset2 = feature B, feature H, feature L, ...; and so on). Same features can also be found in different datasets. The length of each time series is the same.

I am struggling with finding an appropriate ML clustering algorithm to deal with all three dimensions (i. e., time, country, feature). I tried this approach (https://www.pythonforfinance.net/2018/02/08/stock-clusters-using-k-means-algorithm-in-python/), but I can only cluster the feature importances to another. Also, breaking the issue down to 2x2 (either country & feature over time; or weighted features & country) dimensions instead of having 1x3 dimensions results in an information loss.

Is there any ML clustering algorithm in python which can deal with all three dimensions at a time?

Comment: Close-voters: I believe this question is primarily about *statistics*, not *programming*, and that it should therefore stay open/be reopened. See [Closing "software questions".](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5985/1352)